# How to serialize JodaTime using UNIX timestamp format with Jackson

Tags: spring, serialization, jackson, jodatime

I am using

- jackson-annotations-2.4.3.jar
- jackson-core-2.4.3.jar
- jackson-databind-2.4.3.jar
- jackson-datatype-joda-2.4.3.jar

and `Spring 3.2.11`. I am using the joda time's `DateTime` format, and i want to serialize beans that have some date-times as properties. What i would like is to serialize only date-time's timestamp. Instead, jackson serializes the whole object, which leads to problems in js afterwards.
What i am trying to achieved worked when using jackson 1.8.3.

I have tried to register a `JodaModule` to the object mapper for MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter, by defining this in applicationContext.xml. Even though the joda module is loaded, it doesnt seem to work.

1. I tried the following config:

   ```
   <beans:beans>
       <beans:bean id="objectMapper"
           class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.Jackson2ObjectMapperFactoryBean"
            p:simpleDateFormat="yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ">
       </beans:bean>
       <beans:bean
           class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingFactoryBean"
           p:targetObject-ref="objectMapper" p:targetMethod="registerModule">
           <beans:property name="arguments">
               <beans:list>
                   <beans:bean class="com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.joda.JodaModule" />
               </beans:list>
           </beans:property>
       </beans:bean>
   </beans:beans>
   ```
2. After that i tried:

What else should i try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nobody seems to care about this question. However, i will close it, since i have found the answer: i had to save the configuration in a xml file and import it in multiple xml's so that the config would be visible to all the involved contexts.